# How could I set turtles heading to the destination by go along the road

Tags: netlogo

Recently I have discovered the code that helps the turtles to walk along the road that I have assigned the color which is not black.

```
let target one-of patches in-cone 1.5 180 with [pcolor != black]
if target != nobody
  [
    face target
    move-to target
  ]
```

But my problem is that

1. When the turtles meet the dead end, it stops right there and not moving anymore.
2. My turtles already have its own destination to go to (This model is another one). If I use the code that I have mentioned before, maybe it doesn't work. So how could I fix this?

Here is some code that I wrote (Another model).

```
ask turtles
  [
    set wlocation one-of patches with [pcolor = pink]
    move-to wlocation
    set myhome wlocation
  ]
```

After this, I will let turtles wander around in the model. Then in some specific time, turtles will go back to its home by the following code. When the turtles reach its home, it will stay still.

```
ifelse distance myhome > 2
  [face myhome fd random 3]
  [wander]

to wander
  ifelse random 2 = 0 [rt random 30] [lt random 30]
end
```

Does anyone have any idea or suggestion?